# Group by several results SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'd like to have a result grouped by a propertie.

Here's an example about what I would like to retrieve:
[image]

And here's come the table definition :
[image]

I tried this but it does not work :

```
SELECT      OWNER.NAME, DOG.DOGNAME
WHERE       OWNER.ID = DOG.OWNER_ID
AND         OWNER.NAME = (SELECT OWNER.NAME FROM OWNER);
```

But it returns me an error:

> 1427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Based on Alex's response, a modified version of the query would be:

`SELECT OWNER.NAME, DOG.DOGNAME 
 FROM OWNER 
 LEFT JOIN DOG ON OWNER.ID = DOG.OWNER_ID 
 ORDER BY OWNER.NAME`

Comment: It returns me the same error. Yes indeed, it returns more than one result.

Comment: After I posted the reply I realized that the response left by Alex (the other Alex) is better... With an ORDER BY clause is better Did you tried that one? It would be `SELECT      OWNER.NAME, DOG.DOGNAME
FROM        DOG
LEFT JOIN   OWNER
ON          OWNER.ID = DOG.OWNER_ID
ORDER BY OWNER.NAME`

Comment: That's nice :D This is what I want ! Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: :-)   That is not fair :-) You switched completely your answer :-) :-D Switch left right tables then ;-)

Comment: Sorry! Your answer was right but I couldn't comment on it before... When my answer got accepted I needed to edit it so it reflected the final version of the query... Again sorry, didn't mean to steal the answer!

Comment: No problem :-) Just kidding :-) But I believe  OP need all owners returned even they don't have any dogs so we need to switch tables `owner` is the left one

Comment: Ok! I switched the tables

Answer (score 1):

I am not Oracle expert, but I believe you need `FROM` and `JOIN` part :-) :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8630/1

```
SELECT      OWNER.ID, OWNER.NAME,
            DOG.ID, DOG.DOGNAME
FROM        OWNER
LEFT JOIN   DOG
ON          OWNER.ID = DOG.OWNER_ID;
```

Comment: It is working, but not displayed like an array grouped by OWNER.NAME. I thought it was something with a group by...

Answer (score 0):

First up, you are missing the table clauses:

And if you put those in, you still have a problem if you have multiple owners with the same name, where the sub-select in the where clause is returning multiple rows:

---

AND         OWNER.NAME = (SELECT OWNER.NAME FROM OWNER);

If NAME is not distinct, this raises the error.

You could change it to:

AND         OWNER.NAME IN (SELECT OWNER.NAME FROM OWNER);

Although in this case the entire clause is meaningless as the whole table will always be returned

Final answer:

```
SELECT      OWNER.NAME, DOG.DOGNAME
FROM        OWNER, DOG
WHERE       OWNER.ID = DOG.OWNER_ID;
```